# App name doesn't change language after user changes it programmatically

Tags: java, android, string

I give my user the opportunity to change the app language. I use this:

```
public void languageToLoad(String language) {
    String lang = language;
    Locale locale = new Locale(lang);
    Locale.setDefault(locale);
    Configuration config = new Configuration();
    config.locale = locale;
    getBaseContext().getResources().updateConfiguration(config,
            getBaseContext().getResources().getDisplayMetrics());
}
```

for english: languageToLoad(en) or french: languageToLoad(fr)

But my problem is that the app name won't change.

**strings.xml (en):**

```
<string name="app_name">SoccerPro</string>
```

**strings.xml (fr):**

```
<string name="app_name">FootballPro</string>
```

Every string changes its value but not 'app_name'.

If the device language gets changed then it changes but not like my way. What am I doing wrong?

Comment: "But my problem is that the app name won't change" -- where are you looking for it to change?

Comment: At the homescreen of my device. Under the app icon

Comment: Have you tried rebooting the device?

Answer (score 2):

Your call to `updateConfiguration()` affects *your process* at most. It does not affect other processes. Which means that unless your app *is* the home screen, the home screen will not change. `updateConfiguration()` does not affect the user's language at a system level, and AFAIK there is no way for an ordinary SDK app to do that.

Comment: so there is no way to do that?

Comment: @Feuer1978: I do not know what "that" refers to, sorry.

Comment: changing the value of 'app_name' programmatically for the home screen

Comment: @Feuer1978: About the only thing that you can try is to have N `<activity-alias>` elements in your manifest, one for every language, pointing to a language-specific string resource *name* (e.g., `app_name_fr`, not just `app_name`). Each would have the `MAIN`/`LAUNCHER` `<intent-filter>`, but only your default language would be enabled. Then, use `PackageManager` to enable/disable the components necessary to have the `<activity-alias>` for the selected language be the one that is enabled. Not all home screens will accept this without a reboot, though.

Comment: @Feuer1978: Beyond that, you have no way even to tell the home screen that you would like a different language, let alone for the home screen to know what language it is and what string to show. Please bear in mind that there are hundreds, if not thousands, of home screen implementations, and so the further outside the norm you go in interacting with them, the more likely it is that you will run into inconsistent behavior.